# Deleting oracle table using RJDBC

Tags: r, oracle, rjdbc

Is there a way to delete (truncate) a table in R using oracle function? I am using JDBC to connect to oracle; I would like truncate the contents and then load new data into the table.

For instance:

```
select employee_info into variable_name;
```

This will execute the function and load `NULL` (if successful) or `error_message` into `variable_name`.  Next step…check contents of `variable_name`.  If `NULL`, proceed with insert.

```
If variable_name IS NULL THEN
     INSERT INTO
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can execute in Oracle:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE employee_info
```

I don't know R but it's should be:

```
dbGetQuery(conn, "TRUNCATE TABLE employee_info")
```

Comment: `dbSendUpdate`  should be used