# create / drop view / table using rjdbc

Tags: r, rjdbc

I am trying to automate an analytic process using rjdbc. I am looking for **a way to create and drop a view from within R**, using the rjdbc package.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. You should include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

found it

dbSendUpdate(conn, "drop view VIEW_NAME")

dbSendUpdate allows you to send queries without retrieving data, so it is possible to use this method to create, drop, and manipulate views and tables

Comment: how could you create a table and send the values from the existing df using this?

Answer (score 0):

or you can use dplyr::db_drop_table to drop the table